# How much in advance can you apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I have to travel for a summer course in August in Netherlands but before that i travel to Saudi Arabia in June. I'll have to submit my passport to saudi embassy around the mid of may and i return back mid July. Keeping all this in view can i apply for the visa rn? I'm from Pakistan.